# SQL Loop Help. Loop not stopping

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

Trying to copy a rowID column from table 1 and paste it into table 2 using a loop. As table 1 has more rows than table 2, I need it to stop when I hit the end of table 2.
My current syntax endlessly loops and I can't quite figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
declare @cntid int
declare @newrowid int
declare @cnttotal int
set @cntid = 1
set @newrowid = (select top 1 RowID from Invoicing.dbo.Entries where ContractID = 21)
set @cnttotal = (select count(*) from PSPS_transmission.dbo.historical_raw_data)
while @cntid < @cnttotal
    begin
        update PSPS_transmission.dbo.historical_raw_data
        set rowIDraw_data = @newrowid
        set @cntid = @cntid + 1
        set @newrowid = @newrowid + 1
    end
```

Table 1 contains

```
RowID
45351
45352
45353
45354
45355
```

Table 2 contains this after running my posted code. But I need it to be incremented like Table 1.

```
rowIDraw_data
45351
45351
45351
45351
45351
```

Comment: For some reason the code posted weirdly.

Comment: well you could start by editing your question and showing which one is table1 an which one is table2? thanks!

Comment: This looks like SQL-Server, not MySQL. MySQL doesn't have `TOP 1` or `dbo`.

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement so it only updates 1 row. You're updating all rows with the new row ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a loop, you can simply update with a query like:

```
declare @newrowid int = (select max(RowID) from Invoicing.dbo.Entries where ContractID = 21);

with q as
(
   select rowIDraw_data,  @newRowId + row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 rowIDraw_data_new
   from PSPS_transmission.dbo.historical_raw_data
)
update q
set rowIDraw_data = rowIDraw_data_new;
```